# Mark a Jira ticket fixed from within an SVN commit

Tags: svn, jira

I was wondering if its possible to have Jira update a ticket's status to fixed based on parsing an SVN commit and finding Fixed or some other flag in conjunction with the Jira Id? It seems the Jira svn plugin will list the commits that contain a particular ticket id so maybe this is not too much of a stretch. Anyone use this kind of thing with Jira and SVN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Google Code tracker/SVC integration](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/IssueTracker#Integration_with_version_control) does that
- Some nice [Use cases](http://www.javalinux.it/wordpress/2009/10/17/google-code-issue-tracker-integration-with-version-control-using-git-commit-template) including offline work
- Jira Studio does this out of the box, called [Actioning Issues via Commit Messages](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRASTUDIO/Actioning+Issues+via+Commit+Messages)
- It is possible (though not quite easy) to [add it to Jira](http://blogs.atlassian.com/developer/2009/10/dragon_slayer_supplement_action_issues_with_commit_commands.html)

  - It refers to the [Atlassian Dragon Quest](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ATLAS/Here+Be+Dragons)

Comment: Thanks for the info Vladimir, I'll look into Dragon Quest more, its clear though that this is not something standard or easy that Jira does so that answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

This https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/10017 may be the one you are looking for